# Как прижать один из Layout-ов к правой части?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

В размете два `LinearLayout` слева и справа.

1. Как прижать правый (второй) `LinearLayout` к правой части?
2. Как отдать все оставшееся пространство левому `LinearLayout`, чтобы убрать "жесткий размер" (в `200dp`)?

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="200dp" >
        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/flipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Рисовать" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Установки" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для первого `LinearLayout`:

1. Измените значение атрибута `android:layout_width` с `200dp` на `0dp`;
2. Задайте атрибут `android:layout_weight="1"`.

В таком случае второй `LinearLayout` по ширине будет занимать только необходимое ему пространство, а всю оставшееся пространство будет распределено для первого `LinearLayout`.

Итоговый `layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/flipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Btn1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Рисовать" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Установки" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Все заработало! Огромная благодарность!!!